# Run Java webapp under Netbeans with tomcat 5.5 and Java 1.5

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, netbeans, myeclipse

I wass wondering why I can't setup an enviroment with Netbeans 6.9.1 in combination with Tomcat 5.5 and Java 1.5.

[image]

I can only choose for Java 1.4. Is this a restriction of Netbeans? In the past this web application has run under Myeclipse tomcat 5.5 and Java 1.5. But because of the huge memory issues of myeclipse I want to try Netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSEE 1.4 means not Java 1.4 it means the Java Enterprise Version 1.4 (Servlet 2.3). 
You can use JSEE 1.4 with Java 5 or 6.

Comment: your right... JSEE 1.4 doesn't give any problems. only the combinations netbeans tomcat 5.5 s*cks

Answer (score 0):

Check your JAVA_HOME environment setting to see which JDK Tomcat is using. That might the the problem. It is located in your catalina.bat or catalina.sh point it to the right jdk.